# Accessing Windows Credential Manager from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008, credential-manager

I'm using PowerShell 2.0 (necessary because of SP2010) On Windows Server 2008 R2. I need to retrieve credentials for a process from the Windows Credential Manager. I can't seem to make it work.

I was given this piece of code:

```
[Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
(new-object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault).RetrieveAll() | % { $_.RetrievePassword(); $_ }
```

both lines of code throw errors

```
Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime : Unable to find type [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

and

```
(new-object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault).RetrieveAll() | % {$_.RetrievePassword(); $_ }
```

respectively. I've been trying to somehow import the PasswordVault class. So far Google has failed me, I haven't even been able to find out which assembly it resides in. What am I missing?

Comment: That piece of code assumes Windows Runtime which was introduced in Windows Server 2012. [PasswordVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault) is not supported on Windows Server 2008. I can't guide you further as I don't have Windows Server 2008 at hand. You would probably need to use alternative APIs, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944064/ is one example.

Answer (score 48):

In powershell5 type:

```
   Install-Module CredentialManager -force
```

Then

```
   New-StoredCredential -Target $url -Username $ENV:Username -Pass ....
```

and later

```
   Get-StoredCredential -Target ....
```

Source code for the module is https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager

== EDIT 2023 ==

Original is archived, install newer fork with:

```
   Install-Module -Name TUN.CredentialManager
```

Check out [Github repository](https://github.com/echalone/PowerShell_Credential_Manager) for more details.

Comment: OP specifically asked for PS2, why is a PS5 answer being voted up so much?  `Install-Module` is not a valid cmdlet in PS2

Comment: You can install the module on PS2 nevertheless. `Install-Module` is only shortcut.

Comment: The module is no longer being maintained ("I am no longer working on this project or PowerShell much at all. If anyone else wants to take a fork and continue supporting this project. I would be happy to link to that project from here to guide people in the right direction.").

Comment: Hi, I've created a new module forked from the CredentialManager module of Dave, just install TUN.CredentialManager instead of CredentialManager (so call "Install-Module TUN.CredentialManager -Force" ) and you'll get a PowerShell Core compatible version along with more than 512 byte password length support and internal use of secure string instead of storing the clear password (where possible according to cmdlet calls, see new parameters IncludeSecretPassword and ExcludeClearPassword). New website here: https://github.com/echalone/PowerShell_Credential_Manager

Comment: @MarkusSzumovski you should probably inform the original owner so that he can update the description of his Github  "I would be happy to link to that project from here to guide people in the right direction." https://github.com/davotronic5000/PowerShell_Credential_Manager

Comment: @virgula24 I have, he never responded ;)

Comment: Thx @MarkusSzumovski,  added this info to above answer

Comment: Cool, thank you @majkinetor :)

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to access the Win32 API to interact with the Credential Manager.

[CredMan.ps1 from the Technet scripting gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde) nicely demonstrates this.

For simpler usage patterns, like just listing principals or adding new credentials, you can also use [`cmdkey`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243.aspx), a built-in Windows Command-line utility for credential management

For reusing stored Credentials in PowerShell, this guy seems to have found a way to build a `PSCredential` from a Generic Credential handle from the Credential Store, using a technique similar to that of CredMan.ps1: [Get-StoredCredential](http://www.automatedops.com/blog/2013/06/07/get-storedcredentials-module/)

Comment: Thanks, just to make sure, before I devote time to studying it, it will allow me to retrieve the password, right?

Comment: No, at least `cmdkey` won't. Why would you ever want to retrieve a password?

Comment: Because I need to invoke a process remotely with credentials stored in Credential Manager. I thought this part was self-evident, why else would I need to access Credential Manager if not to use the credentials stored inside?

Comment: Without having any practical experience with implementing such a solution, I would think the "proper" way to do so would be to export a token or a security context through an SSPI or similar, instead of fiddling with the password in plain-text directly

Comment: I'm using an instance of System.Management.Automation.PSCredential in the script, so if you know of a way to get that out of the Credential Manager, I'm all ears. I mean eyes.

Comment: cmdkey won't retreive the password, but CredMan.ps1 does because it uses the Credential Manager Win32 API. The password it retrieves is stored/displayed in plain-text, so after you get it you'll need to ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText-Force

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen hello Mathias, is there any restriction for Credential Manager over network? WinAPI CredWrite fails for me if I connect to windows remotely. I asked this here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174185/does-windows-block-access-to-credential-manager-for-remote-connections

Answer (score 10):

If anybody just wants a code snippet so that they can distribute scripts without having to instruct the end users to install modules or include DLL files, this should do the trick.

```
$code = @"
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CredManager {
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public struct CredentialMem
  {
    public int flags;
    public int type;
    public string targetName;
    public string comment;
    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lastWritten;
    public int credentialBlobSize;
    public IntPtr credentialBlob;
    public int persist;
    public int attributeCount;
    public IntPtr credAttribute;
    public string targetAlias;
    public string userName;
  }

  public class Credential {
    public string target;
    public string username;
    public string password;
    public Credential(string target, string username, string password) {
      this.target = target;
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
    }
  }

  public class Util
  {
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CredReadW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CredRead(string target, int type, int reservedFlag, out IntPtr credentialPtr);

    public static Credential GetUserCredential(string target)
    {
      CredentialMem credMem;
      IntPtr credPtr;

      if (CredRead(target, 1, 0, out credPtr))
      {
        credMem = Marshal.PtrToStructure<CredentialMem>(credPtr);
        byte[] passwordBytes = new byte[credMem.credentialBlobSize];
        Marshal.Copy(credMem.credentialBlob, passwordBytes, 0, credMem.credentialBlobSize);
        Credential cred = new Credential(credMem.targetName, credMem.userName, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(passwordBytes));
        return cred;
      } else {
        throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve credentials");
      }
    }

    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CredWriteW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool CredWrite([In] ref CredentialMem userCredential, [In] int flags);

    public static void SetUserCredential(string target, string userName, string password)
    {
      CredentialMem userCredential = new CredentialMem();

      userCredential.targetName = target;
      userCredential.type = 1;
      userCredential.userName = userName;
      userCredential.attributeCount = 0;
      userCredential.persist = 3;
      byte[] bpassword = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
      userCredential.credentialBlobSize = (int)bpassword.Length;
      userCredential.credentialBlob = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(password);
      if (!CredWrite(ref userCredential, 0))
      {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
      }
    }
  }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
# How to store credentials
[CredManager.Util]::SetUserCredential("Application Name", "Username", "Password")
# How to retrieve credentials
[CredManager.Util]::GetUserCredential("Application Name")
# How to just get the password
[CredManager.Util]::GetUserCredential("Application Name").password
```

The above code was tested on PowerShell 7 and PowerShell 5, though you may need a somewhat recent version of the .Net framework if you're using the latter.

Answer (score 5):

[SecretManagement and SecretStore](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement) from Microsoft appear to be the official solution. They were [officially released on March 25, 2021](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available/). The secret can be a credential.

```
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement
Install-Module SecretManagement.JustinGrote.CredMan  # windows credential manager
Register-SecretVault SecretManagement.JustinGrote.CredMan
Set-Secret -Name TestSecret -Secret "TestSecret"
Get-Secret -Name TestSecret -AsPlainText
```

```
TestSecret
```

Comment: The modules was officially released on March 25, 2021 (1.0) and updated (1.1) on July 13, 2021. KUTlime's comment no longer applies.

Comment: Please also note that with `SecretManagement` `powershell` module you can't use arbitrary credential name, since this module prepends `ps:` in credential name. For example, you will be unable to store and retrieve `git:` credentials.

Comment: Minimum PowerShell version: 5.1. How is it relevant to the question about PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: I am getting error : `Set-Secret: Unable to set secret because no vault was provided and there is no default vault designated`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs, the PasswordVault class isn't supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.

> **Minimum supported server** Windows Server 2012

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx

Comment: Alright, point taken. Therefore my question is, how do I access Credential Manager on Windows Server 2008? There must be a way.

Answer (score 2):

I found a really good post, this code will print all usernames, resources and passwords

```bsh
[Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
$vault = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault
$vault.RetrieveAll() | % { $_.RetrievePassword();$_ }
```

Credits to [Todd's post](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=606)

Comment: Mind the environment in the question before reposting good posts. How is it relevant to Windows Server 2008/PowerShell 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

A solution for *Windows PowerShell v5.1* (and *possibly* earlier versions) as well as [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

The [`BetterCredentials`](https://github.com/Jaykul/BetterCredentials) module, [available in the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/BetterCredentials) provides programmatic access to CredMan (Windows Credential Manager).

You can install, e.g., with:

```bash
Install-Module BetterCredentials -AllowClobber
```

`-AllowClobber` is necessary, because the module's `Get-Credential` command is meant to override the [built-in one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential): it is syntax-compatible with the built-in one while offering additional functionality via additional parameters.<sup>[1]</sup>

Notably, the `-Store` switch can be used to store the returned credentials in CredMan.

For more control over how the entry is stored, use `Set-Credential`.

`Get-Credential` automatically returns already-stored credentials, if available, and if only a username was originally specified, it is also sufficient for retrieval.

The following commands, which explicitly interact with the CredMan vault, require the full entry *target name*, as indicated in the `.Target` property values of the decorated `[pscredential]` instances that `Find-Credential` returns.

- E.g., for credentials stored with `Get-Credential -Store -UserName Foo`, the `.Target` property value is `LegacyGeneric:target=MicrosoftPowerShell:user=foo`

`Find-Credential` lists all stored credentials by default; while it does have a `-Filter` parameter, it is severely limited and in my experience doesn't work reliably (as of module version 4.5) - better to use *post-filtering* with `Where-Object`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77367822/45375).

To remove stored credentials, use `Remove-Credential`.

To test whether credentials with a given target name already exist in the CredMan vault, use `Test-Credential`.

---

<sup>[1] It's unlikely that you'll need to, but you can still invoke the overridden cmdlet, namely via `Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Get-Credential`</sup>