# scripting control userpassword2

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, windows-server-2008

We have some systems that require a specific windows user to be logged in so that a required application may run. Though it is not my preferred method, I require the systems to login automatically after startup/reboot. I have seen instructions that require modifying the registry. The only issue I have with this method is that the password is stored a clear text. I wold prefer to use the same method that "control userpassword2" uses, with out having to touch each box manually.

Does anyone know if there is a way to invoke calls to the control panel application "userpassword2" ? if so do you have an example?

(powershell is preferred).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Windows Credential Manager from PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103238/accessing-windows-credential-manager-from-powershell)

Comment: @sodawillow Can the credential manager be used for auto-logon after system startup?

Comment: I don't know. Probably not a duplicate then.

Comment: [Here](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.fr/2011/10/powershell-set-secureautologon.html) you can find what seems to be a more secure way of doing it via the registry.

Comment: Rather than storing it in plain text you can also use `ConvertFrom-SecureString` to change a SecureString into an encrypted standard string, which can be saved to a file.