# Can we encrypt Environment Variable Consists of Password through Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, environment-variables, windows-server-2016

Hi I am trying to create Environment variable through Powershell that consist Password but I guess it needs to encrypted. But When i am trying with below code it's not working. But I need to encrypt it. Can it's possible to encrypt it and no one can see the password.

```
try {
    $sourceFile1 = "C:\vault\service_acct_pass.json"
    $RowValues = Get-Content $sourceFile1  | Select -skip 1 | select-string -pattern '---' -notmatch
    $RowValues = $RowValues -replace '\s{1,}',"`t" | out-file -filepath C:\vault\output.txt
    $sourceFile = "C:\vault\output.txt"
    $RowValues = Get-Content $sourceFile
    $Line = $RowValues.split("`t")
    $columnCount = (Import-Csv $sourceFile -Delimiter "`t" | get-member -type NoteProperty).count
    $myArray = @()
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $columnCount; $i++) {
        $myArray += $Line[$i]
    }
    $columnSource = import-csv $sourceFile -Delimiter "`t"
    foreach ($element in $myArray) {
    ConvertTo-SecureString "[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($element,$columnSource.$element,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)" -AsPlainText -Force
    }
    Remove-Item $sourceFile -Recurse
    }
catch {
  "Unforeseen Errors"
  $error[0]
}
```

**Note**: In the above code I am reading a file that is having key and password. When I am only using this line **[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($element,$columnSource.$element,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)** instead of **ConvertTo-SecureString "[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($element,$columnSource.$element,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)" -AsPlainText -Force** this its works fine and save the variables but it's visible to everyone.

Comment: Your `ConvertTo-SecureString` line is actually doing exactly what you tells it to. The `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` part is just interpreted as any text by ConvertTo-SecureString. First, I'm not sure why you would want this in an environment variable to begin with (and depending on how you are planning to use it, it might not even work) but you will have to convert the value in the desired variable (the one holding the password) rather than the class and method used to store the env var.

Comment: Lets Ignore `ConvertTo-SecureString`. Any suggestion How we can convert the password in Environment variables to be encrypted.

Comment: This seems like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  What are you planning to do with password if you get it working?  Perhaps there is a better solution than this to your actual problem.

Comment: I'd rather you ignored using the env vars for whatever problem you are trying to solve. The problem isn't with `ConvertTo-SecureString`, it's how you are trying to use it. In order to demonstrate you could try running `Write-Output "Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD"` and compare it to running `Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD`. Same phenomenon.

Comment: Maybe you should look into the [Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29103238/1701026) instead of environment variables

Comment: @boxdog , I have .net code running in the server which have hard-coded password in it, I want to to make it dynamically so that it can take value from Environments variable.

Comment: @iRon : I don't think so the credential manager will work on this scenario.

Comment: @notjustme : can you please elaborate more on the this scenario.