# Can we get the TFS credentials using VS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019

I forgot my TFS credentials but i m connected to the Azure server  with visual studio can i get them back using visual studio ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio stores its credentials in the Windows Credential Manager. You can open up that PowerShell and extract it:

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62494685/736079

Comment: actually we can retreive the credentials without powershell using "control panel > user accounts > credential manager"