# How to add credentials to the registry and use them in Powershell scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'd like to add credentials to the registry, but don't know where. Then I would like to use these credentials in a PowerShell script for new-psdrive. The user is a domain user, but the computer is not.
Where to add credentials in the registry?
How to assign credentials from a registry key to a variable?

Comment: Your question is interesting, but too broad. Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029496/45375) shows you how to persist credentials in a _file_, which you could adapt to your needs (note: use on Windows only).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Credential Manager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0). With this module you can store credentials on your workstation and retrieve it for your scripts.
Here is an example how to use [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103238/accessing-windows-credential-manager-from-powershell).
This are the four commands this module provides:

```
Get-Command -Module CredentialManager


CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-StoredCredential                               2.0        CredentialManager
Cmdlet          Get-StrongPassword                                 2.0        CredentialManager
Cmdlet          New-StoredCredential                               2.0        CredentialManager
Cmdlet          Remove-StoredCredential                            2.0        CredentialManager
```

Some further well written [blog post](https://www.scriptinglibrary.com/languages/powershell/how-to-manage-secrets-and-passwords-with-credentialmanager-and-powershell/).

To note, this module does not work for PowerShell Core.