# Reference to [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential] in PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, dll, windows-runtime, passwordvault

I want to port an existing PowerShell script written in PowerShell 5.1 to PowerShell 7.1. However it seems I can't create objects of type [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential] as the type can not be found.

Having a look at the registry tells me this class is stored at the following locations:

- C:\Windows\System32\vaultcli.dll
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vaultcli.dll

But adding these DLLs to my script in PS 7.1 fails:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\System32\vaultcli.dll"        
Add-Type: Bad IL format. The format of the file 'C:\Windows\System32\vaultcli.dll' is invalid.
PS C:\Users\xxx> Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vaultcli.dll"
Add-Type: Bad IL format. The format of the file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vaultcli.dll' is invalid.
```

Checking the related codebase parameter in PowerShell 5.1 returns the following:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault].Assembly.CodeBase
file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/WinMetadata/Windows.Security.winmd
```

How can I correctly add a reference to this type?

Comment: It *might* be because that's a WinRT assembly - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential?view=winrt-20348#applies-to. There's a workaround here that might help - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13042#issuecomment-653357546

Comment: I came upon this post after searching and finding your post.

Maybe this can help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103238/accessing-windows-credential-manager-from-powershell