# How to get the date when your credentials were changed on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, credential-manager

When you connect to the Outlook account, a 'MicrosoftOffice16_Data:SSPI:user@domain.com' entry is created in the credential manager. How can I get the modification date of this record in Powershell?

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @takeshisan. Note that you can help future readers by clearly signaling which answer, if any, solved your problem, namely by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/248777) it.

Answer (score 1):

- You can install the [`BetterCredentials`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/BetterCredentials) module from the PowerShell Gallery, e.g. with:

  ```
  Install-Module BetterCredentials -AllowClobber
  ```
- Then use its `Find-Credential` command to locate the credentials of interest and examine the `.LastWriteTime` property:

  ```
  Find-Credential | 
    Where-Object Target -like *:*=MicrosoftOffice16_Data:SSPI:user@domain.com |
    ForEach-Object LastWriteTime
  ```

  - You may have to tweak the [wildcard pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) passed to the `-like` operator to find the desired credentials.
  - Note that while `Find-Credential` itself has a `-Filter` parameter, the patterns it supports are very limited (only a single `*`, and only on *either* end of the pattern) and even then they don't seem to work reliably (as of v4.5 of the module).